# Is there a way to filter a vector before it's evaluated?

Tags: r

How do I filter "ignore" out of the below `files` vector before it has been evaluated? I tried using the `!!` operator but I don't think I'm doing it right. Here's what I've tried

```
files <- list.files()[!!files != 'ignore')
```

I know I could easily define the vector first and then filter it, but I want to do it all in the same line.

Here's a sample vector of files:

```
files <- c("app.R", "global.R", "ui.R", "server.R", "ignore")
```

Comment: Excellent, that worked! Thanks for that, been wondering how to do this for a while.

Comment: `setdiff(list.files(), "ignore")`

Comment: Ooooo, that's way better.

Comment: Please post these as answers (@ksinva, if the original commenters don't do it you are welcome to use these comments to answer your own question - that is both allowed and encouraged)

Comment: **very** ugly, but for completeness: ````list.files() |> bind_cols() |> filter(`...1` != "ignore") |> pull(`...1`)````

Answer (score 0):

```
Filter(\(x) x != 'ignore', list.files())
```

or

```
with(list(x = list.files()), x[x != 'ignore'])
```